# RequiredFieldValidator sometimes does not work, but unable to reproduce it

Tags: jquery, asp.net, webforms, requiredfieldvalidator

I am debugging an APS.Net Webform application that sometimes accepts an empty value from a textbox field.  It seems that the RequiredFieldValidator does not working. In web log, all incidences seemed to be related to IE 11.0 browser, no minor version data available. The jQuery file used is jquery-1.7.1.min.js,  httpRuntime targetFramework is 4.5, and IIS app pool is ASP.NET v4.0. Also, the validation setting used is

```
<add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="None" lockItem="false" />
```

I read some posts online, and some of them pointed to .Net framework version and jQuery validation in IE 11 browser. However, I was unable to reproduce the issue using IE 11.0 updated version 11.0.105(KB4480965). See code below.

```
<span class="Bold">Item ID</span>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtItemID" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtItemID" ErrorMessage="Error" InitialValue="" SetFocusOnError="true" Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="Add"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
<asp:Button ID="btnAdd" runat="server" OnClick="btnAdd_Click" Text="Add an Item" ValidationGroup="Add" />
```

Comment: When is validation supposed to occur? If it's a button then please post the markup of button. You need to make sure that the validation group on button is same as the validation group on required field valudator.

Comment: Hi Sunil, thanks for your reply.  I have updated my post with submit button markup code.  The validation kicks in as expected, however, occasionally, an empty value was entered into database. The application has been running since 2014, and the first incidence was happened in Apr. 2018.  Since then, there are total of 18 records that missed Item ID value, out of 200K records.

Comment: Add `EnableClientScript="True"` to the required field validator, and also in code-behind before saving to database in button click event,  check with following code: `if(!Page.IsValid) { return;} //skip remainder of click event logic`. This server-side check if very important since required field validator always validates automatically on server-side in case the client-side passed. Also, set `CausesValidation="True"` for the button element in markup.

Comment: Thanks Sunil.  Will give it a try.